# What other are the commonly used hadith collections (besides the famous 6), and what is their relative authenticity?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

What other are the commonly used hadith collections (besides the famous 6 i.e. `Saheeh Muslim, Saheeh Bukhari, Jami'at al-Tirmidhi, Muwatta Malik, Sunan Abi Dawood and Sunan An-Nisai`), and what is the relative authenticity of these other sources ?

Comment: http://sunnah.com lists all widely used and accepted hadiths, and mentions the authenticity of each hadith. you may find the site useful to both read and search

Comment: @MAKZ Muwatta ibn Malik doesn't seem to have authenticity of ahadith.. and what does "Darussalam" mean, which is mentioned at the end of several authenticity remarks ?

Comment: darussalam is the name of publication. read about muwatta ibn malik in the site of darussalam itself: [link](http://store.dar-us-salam.com/Eng_Hadith/R14.html)

Comment: Thanks.. so Muwatta's authenticity is not available online.. will have to buy the book

Comment: the whole book of malik is authentic. why buy the book if u can find it in a website

Comment: Oh.. I thought it was like other hadeeth collections that required grading by other scholars.. is it not ? That would make it equivalent to Bukhari and Muslim in terms of authenticity

Comment: Oh.. sorry.. I re-read the description... its agreed that its extremely authentic.. thanks

Comment: You forgot sunan ibn Majah and maybe al-Mustadrak of al-Hakim as this book claims to include sahih ahadith not quoted in sahih Muslim and al-Bukhari. Muwatta' Maa´lik is one of the most authentic Hadith collections but you will find 530 of th 700+ Hadiths in most of the Books you mentioned, but it also includes lots of narrations jurisprudence and sayings of sahaba etc., but if you could find the riwaya of Muhammad ibn al-Hassan ash-Sahbayni you'll have an overview of the Haidth sources of abu Hanifa!

Answer (score 1):

Asalamu Alaykum brother.

Other than the 6 books of hadeeth in sunni corpus of hadeeth, we have Imam Malik's Muwatta, Imam Ahmeed Bin Hanbal's Musnad, Imam Shafie's Musnad, Imam Khuzayma's Sahih collection, Imam Hibban's Sahih collection, Sunan al-Darimi.

Imam Malik's Muwatta is the first hadeeth collection which was collected for fiqh issues, and it is authentic. Imam Shafie has said concerning it that it is the second most authentic book on the fact of earth. First and totally authentic being the book of Allah i.e Qur'an.

Imam Ahmed's Musnad is question by many scholars of past and present. It contains Rigorously Authentic, Authentic and Weak Hadeeths.

Imam Ibn Hibban's collection is also Sahih, but many scholars of Islam have found that there are many Weak hadeeths in this collection despite the claims of its author that it is 100 authentic.

Imam Ibn Khuzayma's is also Sahih, but many scholars of Islam have found that there are many Weak hadeeths in this collection despite the claims of its author that it is 100 authentic.

Imam Shafie's books can also be considered equal to Musnad of Ahmed

of others, I don;t have adequate knowledge.

Comment: Just to clarify, the difference between the Sahihs of ibn Hibban and ibn Khuzaimah and the other Sahihs is one of methodology (in particular, their assumption about who can be said to be a trustworthy narrator). It doesn't mean that there is a doubt about Sahih hadith in general.